# AngularJS controller is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I can't find the mistake in my application.
The error stack that i receive is this one:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RepoController' is not a function, got undefined

Here is the code of app.js

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('gitHubViewer',["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/main", {
        templateUrl: "main.html",
        controller: "MainController"
    })
    .when("/user/:username", {
        templateUrl: "user.html",
        controller: "UserController"
    })
    .when("/repo/:usermane/:reponame", {
        templateUrl: "repo.html",
        controller: "RepoController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:"/main"
    });

});



}());
```

here is the code of the controller

```
(function() {


var module = angular.module('gitHubViewer');

var RepoController = function($scope, github, $routeParams) {

    var onRepoDetailsComplete = function(data) {

        $scope.issues = data;
        github.getRepoCotributors($score.username, $scope.reponame).then(onRepoCotributorsComplete,onError);

    };

    var onRepoCotributorsComplete = function(data) {


        $scope.repoContribuors = data;

    };

    var onError = function(reason) {

        $scope.error = reason;

    }

        $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
        $scope.reponame = $routeParams.reponame;
        github.getRepoDetails($score.username, $scope.reponame).then(onRepoDetailsComplete,onError);

};

module.controller('RepoController',["$scope","github","$routeParams",RepoController]);

}());
```

Can you please have a look becuase I really can't find teh mistake that I made.

Regards

Fabio

Comment: can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: Make sure you have imported the RepoController file. The error usually occurs when angular couldn't find the corresponding controller globally.

Comment: @23tux thank you for your comment. Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/ae047qwVVaHI8GJfJfzP

Comment: Did you fix it? The plnkr doesn't appear to throw an error?

Comment: I haven't fix it unfortunately. You can see the error when you click on one of the repo.

Comment: I don't get that error, i get `Error: $score is not defined`

Comment: You spelt $scope wrong on line 30 of RepoController -  `github.getRepoDetails($score.username, $scope.reponame).then(onRepoDetailsComplete,onError);`

Comment: Can you explain what steps you take to recreate the error? Is it still the same [ng:areq] error or has it changed? I'm not able to recreate it - http://plnkr.co/edit/KIHWNIrIzPwVpZ0MGteB?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, now it works on plunker but it still don't work on my local env. I'll check for soemthing else

Comment: I've copied and pasted into plunker the same code that I have in my local webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does "**$score.username**" come from?

```
 github.getRepoDetails($score.username, $scope.reponame)
```

I think that you are missing a dependency for the $score or you have just misspelled $scope.